# Push notification is being sent to server but doesn't appear on cellphone

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So i have this test application that i'm using to learn how to send push notifications from an external server hosted in my desktop to a virtual device or smartphone.

Then I use a simple form and input title and message and click the submit button to send the notification.

I have triple checked, the encoding of the notification is fine, and I'm able to pass the firebase token from the android app to the server, which stores it in the MySQL database.

Also the app is correctly sending the token and the server_key is also correct (used the built in copy function at firebase website)

Why isn't my notification showing? this is the source code of the script in php to send the notification to firebase:

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key = "AAAA0Tedu0Y:APA91bGF1k9LAVw90LVM9IdWludKeG1ueVo2V7HesN4CVz2KFvcwGvLkDymuHjm0IvfRvZ6wOEu5Q33pBgYDUXopvTOBSDKQJf2zFFp_22gTCrg6zxNxKyw8_0M9ciPLt3YyJOwkmNYR";
$sql = "select fcm_token from fcm_info";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//these lines get the key that has been store (i only store one key from one app, so it takes the first value of the result
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$key = $row[0];

$header = array(
    'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
    );

$field = array( 'to'=>$key,
                'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message)
                );

$payload = json_encode($field);

//If echo $payload, It print the following:
/*
{
    "to":"esM8_IMRWrw:APA91bEVOTjpC5kkqAWqWwEs7gNq5-4iUvL6fC947cfWkg1G0VhKDiuibSOr_xSNcIJ8rb4VewjNJ2Jd_0AXBdQgTbOO0FO-stmP3ymOCLGQlka3s2RQ3854UiPr_puc274hXSlQMLen",
    "notification":{
        "title":"asdasd",
        "body":"asdasd"
    }
}

So the json is properly formatted


*/

/*this generates the http url connection from my server to firebase push notification sending url. I think the error is somewhere in these lines, but i dont know where*/
$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL,$path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);

$result = curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session);
mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the response show any errors?

Comment: nop, no errors, the notification just simply isn't showing at all on the virtual device.

Comment: I actually just tried it again by deletting the entire database and reinstalling the app and it worked once. then it stopped working again

Comment: Make sure your PC and smartphone coneected to same network

Comment: @ArpitPatel they are, I'm also using a virtual device in my own computer, but none are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link to get more information about push notifications

[How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/38795553)